# Nmap returns both, mysql and mariadb versions, how do I khow which one is actually running?

Tags: nmap, mysql, mariadb

I ran `nmap` scan and output included following line:

```
3306/tcp open     mysql    MySQL 5.5.5-10.3.25-MariaDB-0+deb10u1
```

How do I know which one is actually running, MySQL or MariaDB?

Answer (score 1):

MariaDB is a fork of MySQL. The port used and protocol spoken are MySQL. The version string indicates MariaDB.